# TinyMCE strips HTML

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I have got a problem with TinyMCE, in my content manager system I have got several TinyMCE fields included.

The are triggered by a click function on a icon in the click function it calls the function showNewTextEdit.

The problem is that in Internet Explorer 8 all HTML tags are being stripped out of the text. I have tested it in other browsers (Firefox and Chrome). It works perfect in those.

Here my function I use to create the tinymce.

```
function showNewTextEdit(editdiv, value, existing) {
    var textedit = $("<textarea />").addClass("tinymce value").html(value);

    $(editdiv).append(textedit);


    $('.tinymce').tinymce({
        script_url : '/js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js',

        <?php // General options ?>
        language : 'nl',
        theme : "advanced",
        plugins : "safari,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,imagemanager",

        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,forecolor,|,bullist,numlist,hr,|,undo,redo",
        theme_advanced_buttons2 : "copy,paste,cut,|,link,unlink,|,search, removeformat",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "visualaid,tablecontrols",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",

        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,

        content_css : "/css/tinyMceWMS.css",

        theme_advanced_blockformats : "h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6",
        forced_root_block : false,
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        paste_create_paragraphs : false,
        paste_create_linebreaks : false,
        paste_use_dialog : false,
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_convert_middot_lists : false,
        paste_unindented_list_class : "unindentedList",
        paste_convert_headers_to_strong : true,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: false,
        convert_urls : false,
        width : editbreedte,
        height: 400
    });
}
```

Comment: can you create a tinymce fiddle? (http://fiddle.tinymce.com)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change your plugin options slightly.

Take a look at the initialization example:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin3x:paste

The summary next to each plugin option is quite useful.